# I call the method audiomanager.setMode(MODE_IN_CALL) and my earphone doens't work anymore

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager, headset

As I mentioned above, I get the AudioManager instance and initiate it with MODE_IN_CALL, however when I close my app(not killed), I can't make my earphone to work when using other apps, please help.Is it that I set the wrong mode the reason of my problem?
Here's the code:

```
private boolean initDefaultSensor() {
    if (proximitySensor != null) return true;
    if (sensorManager == null || audioManager == null) return false;
    proximitySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    if (proximitySensor == null || audioManager == null) {
        return false;
    }
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    return true;
}
```

also i called some other methods that may be relative to this question

```
public void OpenSpeaker() {
    try {
        if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void CloseSpeaker() {
    try {
        if (audioManager != null) {
            if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Clear audio manager instance in onPause and reassign it in onResume

Comment: @Pro : You added User permissions on Manifest file

Answer (score 1):

As per my research, the `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)`, doesn't work above Android 4.4, and is accessible only by system apps/services. If you try to `getMode()`, you will get `AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL` in return.

However, if you want to use it in Android L, you can use `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)`.